# Advantages of using constructers in java like Wat they r useful like memory reducing or security proposes

Tags: java

1. Memory reducing
2. Security proposes
3. Etc

Comment: If your question is about Java, why did you tag it with javascript and c#? Also, what is your alternative to the use of constructors? Procedural programming?

Comment: You're asking something akin to "What are the advantages to lungs in people? What are they useful for?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They exist because they they let you create instances of objects. The main reason why constructors are useful I can think of (but there are much more of them) is that they let you check in their body if arguments passed to them are correct (but you can perform many checks even in constructor without arguments). For example, look, if you had class `Person`, and you create `Person` with argument of age:

```
class Person {
    int age;
    Person(int age) {
        if(age < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

You don't allow to create new `Person` if you passed wrong age).